# Delphi Xe7 with Dbexpress . Unable to load dbxmss.dll ErrorCode 193

Tags: delphi, dbexpress

I'm Using Delphi Xe7 with Dbexpress in Windows 32 . After Deploy 
The program runs on Windows 64. This problem appears
Unable to load dbxmss.dll (ErrorCode 193). It may be missing from the system Path.
But Does not appear in Windows 32

Comment: The error [`ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT) indicates that you are trying to load a 64-bit library in a 32-bit process (or vice-versa, I'm not sure).

Comment: It has been used to transfer files back and message
Access violation at address 007058E3 in module 'exefile.exe'. Read of address 00000000

Comment: throw exception in try open 
 MainDB.Connected := True;

Comment: Your comments are making little sense

Answer (score 0):

There are two files named *dbxmss.dll* located in the *redist\win32* and *redist\win64* subfolder of your XE7 installation. You have to deploy the one suited for your exe, depending you compiled a 32-bit application or a 64-bit application. It doesn't matter whether the target system is 64-bit or not (despite that you cannot run a 64-bit application on a 32-bit OS).